# Setting Up Google Analytics on Domain Redirected to Leadpages Landing Page

Tags: google-analytics

I am utilizing Leadpages and Google Analytics and I'm having an issue that needs to be resolved.  We have a domain that is redirecting to a Leadpages landing page. Just as an exmaple, I'll call it www.maindomain.com that redirects to www.leadpagesaccount.lpages.co/leadpagename.

I've set up the property in GA as www.maindomain.com (hosted by bluehost) and added the tracking code to the appropriate spot within the LP dashboard. I now realize (if I'm understanding correctly) that GA will not track anything since (per GA troubleshooting knowledge base) js may not catch the hit before the users browser takes them to the LP page that does not have the tag.

The problem then becomes, if I set up the LP URL as the property to be tracked, then all of the users who arrive there via www.maindomain.com will be tracked as coming from www.maindomain.com only and therefore will not deliver accurate results.

How can I configure GA to accurately track traffic that starts at www.maindomain.com and arrives at the www.leadpagesaccount.lpages.co/leadpagename URL? Is this possible?

Please let me know what other information might be needed to solve this and be prepared to educate me on what you did to solve the problem — or, conversely, specifics as to WHY the problem can't be solved if that is the case. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head think there are few ways you can go about this.

1. use cross domain tracking: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033876?hl=en 
   This will link the sessions from www.maindomain.com to your leadpage. In this case, you'll be able to see the user flow and determine how people arrive at leadpage.
2. use campaign parameters on the www.maindomain.com https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en 
   To set this up, I'd suggest you separate www.maindomain.com on to a separate property and treat it as an affiliate site. You would tag the links on maindomain.com to lead page with the UTM parameters. When you do this, people who click on the links will be tagged with the campaigns/source/mediums and on the lead page GA reports, you will be able to identify activities from this campaign.